# How to set a default date parameter to pass to ajax get call in JavaScript, on selecting date value it should change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, date, jsp

I am trying display current date attendance on page load and after selecting a date then I am selecting that date details and displaying it.

Result I am getting and what I need:

Right now my result is:

1. If I search a desired date I am getting both default date data and selected date data.
2. problem is that whenever I click a search button obviously page will reload then default value will function will also run so I am getting both value.

Solution I need is:

1. As I need current date data, I can't change the onload function.
2. And when I click the search button it should take the desired date value not the onload date value so that I can pass it to ajax as a parameter.

Let's consider a input date field and setting this input date field as default ajax call parameter to pass to get a particular data according to parameter passed.

Datesearch.jsp

```
<html><body>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm datepicker" id="DtPicker">
<button type="button" id="Search" onclick=SearchDate()>Search</button
</body></html>
```

Now I am setting default date value Onload from input date field, and on selecting desired date parameter from same date field and on clicking search Button it should pass that preferred parameter to ajax parameter instead of default parameter.

DateSearch.js

```
(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
    $( "#srchVehDtPicker" ).datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        autoclose: true
    });

// Here i am setting default date value to var that is current date that is seeted on the input date field onload.

    var utc = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
    document.getElementById("DtPicker").value =utc;

// calling ajax funtion with default parametr. 
attendance(utc);

}());

// On button click search funtion is called where selected date is collected passed to ajax as parameter
function SearchDate(){

// taking the value from input date value on button click.
    var searchdate = $("#DtPicker").val();
    var utc = searchdate.toString();

// calling ajax value with a value as a parameter.
    attendance(utc);
}

function attendance(utc){
    var url = "projecturl?utc="+utc;
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : url,
            cache : false,  
            contentType: "text/plain",
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(data) 
            {           
                AttendanceDetailsObj = data[0].Result;
                AttendanceList(AttendanceDetailsObj);

            }
    });
}
```

`Attendance.java`

Here i am trying to fetch data according to date passed and i am trying to fetch that are greater than and equal to passed date.

And when default date is passed only that date data should appear not other values.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONArray finalResultAry = new JSONArray();
        String utc = request.getParameter("utc");
        //String utc = "2020-04-29";

        JSONArray AttendanceDetailsRstAry = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject AttendanceDetailsObj = new JSONObject();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement smt = null;

        try {

            DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
            Connection connection = connect.connect();
            smt = connection.createStatement();

            String  attendanceselectallQry = "select * from Attendance where Plan_Date>='"+utc+"'";

            rs = smt.executeQuery(attendanceselectallQry);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    JSONObject AttendanceDetailsRstObj = new JSONObject();
                    AttendanceDetailsRstObj.put("Id",rs.getInt("Employee_ID"));
                    AttendanceDetailsRstObj.put("Name",rs.getString("Employee_Name"));
                    AttendanceDetailsRstObj.put("presenttype",rs.getString("Present_Type"));
                    AttendanceDetailsRstObj.put("plandate",rs.getString("Plan_Date"));
                    AttendanceDetailsRstObj.put("sanctionedon",rs.getString("Sanctioned_On"));
                    AttendanceDetailsRstObj.put("leaveot",rs.getString("Leave_OT"));
                    AttendanceDetailsRstAry.put(AttendanceDetailsRstObj);

                }
            AttendanceDetailsObj.put("Result", AttendanceDetailsRstAry);
            finalResultAry.put(AttendanceDetailsObj);

            smt.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.getWriter().write(finalResultAry.toString());

    }
```

Comment: as you have use `ajax` your page should not get reload , also can you make demo for your current code ?

Comment: on same page i have a datatable view so it will reload

Comment: can anyone solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to check if the page is reloaded for the first time or not .By using this you need to `setItem` in localStorage which  will be used to check if the `item` is set or not depending upon that you can perform required operation.

So, your jquery code will look like below :

```
(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
  $("#srchVehDtPicker").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose: true
  });
  if (window.localStorage) { //checking   value in local storage
    if (!localStorage.getItem('firstLoad')) {
      //settting value in localstorage
      localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
      var utc = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);
      document.getElementById("DtPicker").value = utc;
      console.log("First time load");
      // calling ajax funtion with default parametr. 
      attendance(utc);
    } else {
      //do something 
      console.log("Not loaded first time");
    }
  }

}());
```

**Update 1** : As i have already said that you can use `sessionStorage` to store the value of date and and whenever your page reload check that store data against the default value of date if differ then take `sessionStorage` value else take default value .Your code will look like below :

```
(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
  $("#srchVehDtPicker").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose: true
  });
  var utc = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);
  document.getElementById("DtPicker").value = utc;
  //if there is some value in session
  if (window.sessionStorage) {
    //getting current value in sessionStorage
    var date_value = sessionStorage.getItem("date");
    //value fetch is equal to current date
    if (date_value == utc) {
      //setting current value 
      sessionStorage.setItem("date", utc);
      //calling function
      attendance(utc);

    } else if (date_value != utc) {
      //setting session storage with updated value
      sessionStorage.setItem("date", date_value);
    }


  } else {
    //onload setting session
    sessionStorage.setItem("date", utc);
    attendance(utc);
  }

}());

// On button click search funtion is called where selected date is collected passed to ajax as parameter
function SearchDate() {

  // taking the value from input date value on button click.
  var searchdate = $("#DtPicker").val();
  var utc = searchdate.toString();
  //setting value in session
  sessionStorage.setItem("date", utc)
  // calling ajax value with a value as a parameter.
  attendance(utc);
}
```

(Above code is not tested but , it should work.Sorry for any syntax error)

Comment: when i click  a search button, page reloads and gets the new data to display which includes both default parameter and searched parameter.  as i said if i use window.localStorage it won;t work, scope of  window.storage is until the page reload [for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: what i want is at first when i open a page it should load data using current date(date text box #srchVehDtPicker value:1) which is default parameter, then if i select a different date(date text box #srchVehDtPicker value:2) and search(search button) now i should only get value2 data, should display. problem is: when i search page reloads for some reason and default parameter and searched value parameter is passing through ajax and getting both the data

Comment: You can store the `date` in `sessionStorage` and whenever your page reload check that store data against the default value of date if differ then take `sessionStorage` value else take `default` value

Comment: @Sati give me some example

Comment: I have updated my code test it and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: else {
    //onload setting session
    sessionStorage.setItem("utc", utc);
    attendance(utc);
  }  will work and onload i need to clear datatable before loading new data, i am getting a blank row then after that i am getting values.